# drawAtPoint, clarification needed

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'd like to draw "text" on some location on the screen without using `UILabel`, so i

```
[@"text" drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(100, 200) 
     withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:10.0]];
```

Nothing shows up however, though description of `drawAtPoint` reads:

> Draws the string in a single line at the specified point in the
>   current graphics context using the specified font.

I suspect, my mistake is that i am calling it in my `UIViewController's` `viewDidLoad` method, and not placing onto the view? **(But how?)**

**Again, using this way and avoiding the use of UILabel, how can text be placed on screen at custom location?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to draw a string to a view, you will need to sub class a view and implement the drawRect method

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    [[UIColor whiteColor] set];
    [@"Your string" drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100) withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]];
}
```

> not placing onto the view? (But how?)

Its because the string will be drawn in the curent context that is valid when you are calling it in drawRect, if you call  [@"Your string" drawInRec... from your viewDidLoad it wont work because you dont have a valid context

> Again, using this way and avoiding the use of UILabel, how can text be
>   placed on screen at custom location?

Using `NSString` fro drawing and not `UILabel`, and you can use `drawInRect:withFont`

Comment: +1: And see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Formulaic/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008932-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2 for Apple's sample code.